# Calculate column from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps

I am a beginner at python and dataframes and now I have encountered a problem. I have made a dataframe containing adresses. I want to create a calculated column that shows the distance from my house. I have gotten this far:

```
API_key = 'Very secret api key'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=API_key)


def distance(destination):
    origin = ('44100, Kuhnamontie 1, Finland')
    distance = (gmaps.distance_matrix(origin, destination, mode='driving')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"])/1000
    return distance


df["distance"] = distance(df.Adress)
```

This solution works for the first row in the dataframe but all rows in the column get the same value assigned. I guess the calculation and api-request must be made per row. I guess I could loop through the data frame, but as I understand it - there are better ways.
Can you help me?

Comment: ... I hope this isn’t your actual address.  It’s worth keeping in mind that in this field, you are in the presence of some *very* accomplished hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) should be slightly more efficient than loop:

```
df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda row : distance(row["Adress"]),axis=1))
```